# How do I install Skype for Business on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office, skype

I have been to the Office365 website and looked in the software section but I cannot find it.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: https://blogs.office.com/2016/04/26/skype-for-business-mac-preview-is-here/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft has officially released Skype for Business for Mac on October 26th, 2016. You can find the official download link here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54108

If you are using Homebrew (and Cask), you can install Skype for Business for Mac with the following commands:

```
brew update ; brew cask install skype-for-business
```

Answer (score 8):

Skype for Business has not yet made it in full to the Mac.

Microsoft are instead still offering the older Lync software...

> **Set up Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011 for Office 365**
>
> If your organization is using Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011, you can use it with your Office 365work or school account.
>
> To use Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011 with Office 365 you need to go to the Office 365 portal and click Install Skype for Business (Lync). Note: The Install Skype for Business (Lync) button will only be available if Skype for Business (Lync) was part of your plan and if it has not already been installed.
>
> If you haven’t installed Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011 yet, you can install it from this location: [Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011.](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/7/0/270a2926-6bd7-4cfc-bdb9-4981b33378dc/lync_mac_2011_all.dmg)

Source: [Office KB : "Set up Skype for Business (Lync) for Mac 2011 for Office 365"](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Set-up-Skype-for-Business-Lync-for-Mac-2011-for-Office-365-ae3ebd0e-a1a7-48cf-9350-36b144dc5f88?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA)

Comment: Just for reference, there is a thread here where people are registering their disappointment and disgust in how long Microsoft are taking in providing a Lync which is more recent than 4-5 years old (and performs horribly) https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/166/t/343906

Answer (score 3):

It's due for [release in early 2016 apparently](http://machow2.com/skype-for-business-for-mac/) but in the meantime, Lync 2011 is basically Skype For Business.